# Why is VSCode Python debugger slowing down execution by a factor of 5

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I run a Python 3.10 script that analyzes some 350 SQL files using the `sqlparse` module. When I run this via "Run Python File" in VSCode 1.73.1 it takes about 4 seconds. When I run it via "Debug Python File", it takes roughly 5 times as long.

The final analysis will run on a set of 1,500 SQL files, and debugging something that sits on top of the analysis result (a heavy dependencies network of objects) will probably take more than a minute in each iteration. This will slow down the development cycle considerably, somewhat like in the old times when we had a compile/bind-cycle before we can run our latest change.

I will probably survive, but I am curious: Where does this excessive runtime come from?

Comment: if your code is without "bugs" why use a debugger to run the code, the debugger is there to help you find the cause of bugs, not to run your code in production

Comment: @rioV8 – I am using the analysis result to find out $things about that pile of legacy SQL in a very much trial-and-error mode, perfectly supported by the debugger. And, because I am not superhuman, I keep finding bugs and shortcomings in the analysis when using the result ;-)

Comment: what `analysis result` can't you get without the debugger? Have you tried `Ctrl+F5`

Comment: @rioV8 – 1) I would like to start my interactive exploration in the VSCode debugger based on the result derived from parsing the 350 SQL files. 2) Ctrl+F5 runs the script without VSCode debugger (thus bypassing breakpoints set in the editor) and then halts in Pdb on a breakpoint() statement. Not the best starting point for interactive exploration. 3) Frankly, I am more interested in the "why"...

Comment: if running **IN** the debugger would not slow down execution we would always run in a debugger. Imagine what a debugger has to do and realize it takes a lot of code execution to do it

Comment: you don't have to use a debugger to `parsing the 350 SQL files`, after getting that result you can start a debugger session to use that result

Comment: @rioV8 – _Imagine what a debugger has to do and realize it takes a lot of code execution to do it_ – the details of this I want to learn from a future answer :)

Comment: it executes a **single** statement and analyses if a breakpoint has been hit, if not go to begin of loop